# Entity Framework Code First custom migrations Transaction Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I have defined a custom migration class, like so:

```
public class MyMigrate<TMigrationsConfiguration> : IDatabaseInitializer<MyContext>
    where TMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>, new()
{
    private readonly TMigrationsConfiguration _config;

    public MyMigrate(string connectionString, string invariantProvider)
    {
        var typeInitialCreate = typeof(MyConfiguration);

        var migrationsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeInitialCreate);
        var migrationsNamespace = typeInitialCreate.Namespace;

        _config = new TMigrationsConfiguration
        {
            TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionString, invariantProvider),
            MigrationsAssembly = migrationsAssembly,
            MigrationsNamespace = migrationsNamespace,
        };
    }

    public void InitializeDatabase(MyContext context)
    {
        // Update the migrator with the config containing the right connection string
        var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(_config);

        var dbm = dbMigrator.GetDatabaseMigrations();
        var local = dbMigrator.GetLocalMigrations();
        var pending = dbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations();

        dbMigrator.Update();
    }
}
```

This is the actual configuration class, that does some additional seeding stuff. This class is located in another assembly.

```
public sealed class MyMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public MigrationConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "MyContext";
    }
}
```

This is the generated Configuration file you get after you enable migrations. It is used, to identify and load the assembly with the generated migration files.

```
internal sealed class MyConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "MyContext";
    }
}
```

}

I execute it like so:

```
private static void MigrateToLatest()
    {
        var conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyContext"].ConnectionString;

        Database.SetInitializer(new MyMigrate<MigrationConfiguration>(conString, Migrate.SqlInvariantProvider));

        using (var fctx = new MyContext(conString, "SYSTEM"))
        {
            if (!fctx.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
            {
                fctx.Database.Initialize(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the following error message when i call Initialize(false):

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The transaction passed in is not associated with the current connection. Only transactions associated with the current connection may be used.`

I have checked the connection strings, they seem fine. If i uncomment the Initializer line, or replace it with SetInitializer(null), i will get the "model has changed" error message, but transactions don't seem to be a problem. Somehow it must have to do with my custom migrator class. I used this code in EF 4.3 and it worked. In 6.1.3 it no longer executes.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 connection to the database open? As far as I understand, you can only have 1 connection open at a time with Entity, for example if you are making a connection in another class that is also instantiated, you may get this error.

Comment: Not that i know of. All code that is executed is here.

Comment: On second thought, it might be the DbMigrator that is opening a second connection when it is initialized during Initialize(false) maybe?